# Issue with vee-validate in Vue 3 - Multiple Button Elements Triggering Form Submission

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm currently working on a project using Vue 3 and the [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/) package for form validation. I've encountered an issue where every `<button>` element within my form seems to trigger a form submission, even if the button doesn't have a type of `"submit"`. This behavior is not what I want; I want the form submission to occur only when a button with a type of `"submit"` is clicked.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```js
<template>
  <Form @submit="handleSubmit">
    <input v-model="formData.email" type="email" />
    <input v-model="formData.password" type="password" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
  </Form>
</template>

<script>
import { Form } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        email: '',
        password: '',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      // Form submission logic here
      console.log('Form submitted');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In this example, both the "Submit" and "Cancel" buttons trigger the form submission. I want the form to submit only when the "Submit" button is clicked.

How can I modify my code to ensure that form submission only occurs when a button with a type of "submit" is clicked, and the "Cancel" button does not trigger it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I needed to add `type="button"` to my button element. Buttons without a type attribute trigger form validation by default, and that was causing the issue. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to register the `Form` component in your component:

```
import { Form } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  components: { Form }, // <----- register imported component
  ...
```

Without it, you'll end up with a regular `<form>` element.

Though admittedly, even without the import, I couldn't see the cancel button submitting the form when putting you code in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). If the problem still occurs, consider adding a playground that reproduces the issue to your question.